# Retrieving Data from multidimensional array Object in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array of this format

```
stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 245
    [status] => 1
    [filename] => test_image.png
    [uri] => temporary://test_image.png
    [filemime] => image/png
    [filesize] => 58140
    [source] => upload
    [destination] => temporary://test_image.png
    [fid] => 3312
    [timestamp] => 1394177272
    [type] => image
    [field_replacement] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uid] => 245
            [status] => 1
            [filename] => test_image.png
            [uri] => temporary://test_image.png
            [filemime] => image/png
            [filesize] => 58140
            [source] => upload
            [destination] => temporary://test_image.png
            [fid] => 3312
            [timestamp] => 1394177272
            [type] => image
            [field_replacement] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 245
                    [status] => 0
                    [filename] => test_image.png
                    [uri] => temporary://test_image.png
                    [filemime] => image/png
                    [filesize] => 58140
                    [source] => upload
                    [destination] => temporary://test_image.png
                    [fid] => 3312
                    [timestamp] => 1394177272
                    [original] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [fid] => 3312
                            [uid] => 245
                            [filename] => test_image.png
                            [uri] => temporary://test_image.png
                            [filemime] => image/png
                            [filesize] => 58140
                            [status] => 1
                            [timestamp] => 1394177135
                            [type] => image
                            [rdf_mapping] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [type] => image
                )

            **[original] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [fid] => 3312
                    [uid] => 245
                    [filename] => test_image.png
                    [uri] => temporary://test_image.png
                    [filemime] => image/png
                    [filesize] => 58140
                    [status] => 0
                    [timestamp] => 1394177272
                    [type] => image
                    [rdf_mapping] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )**

        )

)
```

Now Need to retrieve this value

```
           **[original] => stdClass Object
            (
                [fid] => 3312
                [uid] => 245
                [filename] => test_image.png
                [uri] => temporary://test_image.png
                [filemime] => image/png
                [filesize] => 58140
                [status] => 0
                [timestamp] => 1394177272
                [type] => image
                [rdf_mapping] => Array
                    (
                    )
            )**
```

How to do it in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an PHP array. This a php object. So you can access like below using arrow (->).

```
$your_object->field_replacement->original
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$original = $object->field_replacement->original;
var_dump($original);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for ans but i am accepting above answer, I think he need more points. Both answers are right, I hope you understand

Comment: I do, no problem ! :-)